# combine multiple functions with delay

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

what I'm trying to get is:

1. hide column O and P
2. export a pdf of the visible column (not necessary to open a dialog box, but I'm not able to coding and I found only this solution, and also is it possibe to force export to export a full width file?)
3. hide sheet after it has been exported in pdf

I write this combining multiple script i found googling:

```
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var str = '<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'" >';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "scarica il documento in pdf");
}


function nascondifoglio(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
Utilities.sleep(10000);
sheet.hideSheet();
}

function nascondicolonna(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("O:P");
sheet.hideColumn(range);
}

function ESPORTA() {
  nascondicolonna();
  PDF ();
  nascondifoglio();
}
```

it almost works but what i get is that column O and P are hidden AFTER sheet has been hidden, not before, so in my downloaded pdf I got also O and P column visible..

is there a way to better code this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `is it possibe to force export to export a full width file?`. And, in your question, there are multiple requests? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I would like to (in sequence): 1- hide specified column (column O and P), 2- export a pdf of the whole sheet (except column O and P) in full widht scale, 3-hide active sheet (just like it has been exported  and downloaded in pdf and archived) ... in the code i attached column O and P are hidden AFTER file has been exported in pdf (but not in full widht) and sheet has been hided, my result is that i got a pdf that has visible column O and P and that is not weel centered in the page and too small .. thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: in sequence, step by step: 1) active sheet hide column range:O:P. -->   THEN -->  2) active sheet export pdf in full width   --> THEN --> 3)  active sheet hide